# Check if for loop returns values batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have the below script where I loop on txt files in a specific directory, I want to execute what's inside the loop only if any txt files were returned.
I tried using `IF NEQ` but still the loop is entered although there is no txt files in this location.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%I in (%cd%\txt\*.txt) DO (
SET namepath=%%I
echo(%namepath%)
IF [%namepath%] NEQ [""] (
echo entered
)
)
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @npocmaka I added `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` in the beginning but still the loop is entered although there is no .txt files in this directory

Comment: Are you trying to read the text file?

Comment: @npocmaka no, like I want the loop be entered only if %%I had a value which means that there was a txt file in this location.

Comment: But `FOR %%I` lists only existing files...

Comment: @npocmaka Exactly, so why the loop is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%I in (%cd%\*.pzk) DO (
echo ++%%I++
SET namepath=%%I
ECHO (%namepath%^)
CALL ECHO (%%namepath%%^)
IF [%namepath%] NEQ [""] (
echo entered
)
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Miraculously, I had no file named `*.pzk` in the directory, so this ran giving no results.

I then set up `test.pzk` and this produced

> ++c:\106x\test.pzk++
>   ()
>   (c:\106x\test.pzk)
>   entered

Because I echo the name-found between 2 pairs of `+` as sentries, then the value of `namepath` as it was at the time the `for` was encountered (*nothing*) then by calling `echo`, with an extra space inserted before the `(` (as `echo` and `echo(` are interpreted in almost the same way) and finally, `entered` because `[]` is indeed not equal to `[""]`

So - one of your problems is that the `)` in the `echo (%namepath%)` is interpreted as closing the `(` in the `for...do (`. Consequently, `entered` would be `echo`ed.

If you code `if %var%==somevalue goto somewhere` then if `var` is empty, this is resolved to `if ==somevalue goto somewhere`. "quoting the arguments" thus: `if "%var%"=="somevalue" goto somewhere` alleviates the situation.
If you code `if %var%==somevalue goto somewhere` then if `var` is empty, this is resolved to `if ==somevalue goto somewhere`. "quoting the arguments" thus: `if "%var%"=="somevalue" goto somewhere` alleviates the situation. The strings to be compared must be identical in all aspects to be declared "equal".

---

Your code: [Please don't link to off-site resources as they may evaporate]

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%I in (%cd%txt*.txt) DO (
 SET namepath=%%I
 IF [%namepath%] NEQ [""] (
  SET name=%%~nxI
  SET folder=%cd%txt%name%
  CALL ECHO (%%folder%%^)
  CALL ECHO (%%namepath%%^)

  SET folder=%namepath:.trc=!""!%
  call set folder=%%namepath:.txt=%%
  CALL ECHO (%%folder%%^)
  md "%folder%" 2>nul
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

*Code blocks* (parenthesised series of commands) are evaluated at *parse-time* at which point any `%var%`s are replaced by the value of that variable *at that time*. The *entire program* from the `DO (` through to its matching `)` before the `goto :eof` is **one code block** and this procedure will be applied to that entire block when the `for` is first encountered.

If you wish to access the *run-time* value of a variable within a code block, you need to invoke `delayedexpansion` [there are hundreds of SO items about this] when `%var%` **still** means "the parse-time value" and `!var!` means "the run-time value", ie. the value as it changes in the loop.

Note that the `call echo/set...` syntax invokes a sub-process which proceeds with a copy of the *current* environment, hence has the *run-time* values of the main process. So `call echo %%var%%` actually executes a sub-process and uses the fact that `%` is the escape character for `%` to execute the instruction `echo %var%` in the sub-process, which is the *current* value of `var` in the call**ING** process.

```
FOR %%I in (%cd%txt*.txt) DO (
```

Not really sure what you need here. `%cd%` does not include the terminal `\`, so this would mean "the parent directorynametxt*.txt". I believe this may be an error created by the 3rd party site you are using. Here `%cd%\` is the same as `.\` but is redundant in any case, as the current directory is the default.

```
 IF [%namepath%] NEQ [""] (
```

is **always** going to be true *unless* `namepath` contained the value `""` (that is, two rabbits' ears) **at the time that the** `for` **was encountered**.

Since `namepath` is being varied within the code block, you'd need `!namepath!` here to access the run-time value, but it's really not necessary since `namepath` cannot be empty at this point - `%%I` will never be empty - the entire `for` code block will be skipped if there are no matching files.

But - while we're passing through, the syntax `if defined namepath` would detect `namepath` being *nothing* (ie cleared) - **and** `if defined` works on the *run-time* value of the variable.

```
  SET folder=%namepath:.trc=!""!%
```

I've no idea what you intend to do here. It appears to want to replace `.trc` with `!""!` - but I've no notion *why*. Rabbit's ears are not valid file/directoryname characters, so this doesn't seem to make sense. Add in the minor complication that `!` is a special character in `delayedexpansion` mode and the mystery deepens.

Anyway, you overwrite the value of `folder` with the next statement.

Now - that statement should replace any `.txt` with *nothing*. Fair enough, but `namepath` is set to `%%I` and the `for` loop is filtering on `.txt` files - so this should set `folder` to the name-part only of `%%I` or `%%~nI`.

And you should be able to

```
md "%%~nI" 2>nul
```

which obviates the entire gymnastic excercise with `folder` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer. One more thing, if I run my script found here http://pasteall.org/348561 I get this error `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` after debugging I found it coming from this line `if not exist %folder% md %folder%` not sure why? I've tried using mkdir as well but gives the same error.

Comment: Always "quote filename and directorynames" so that if they contain separators, the entire name is interpreted as a single token. It's not requireed to check whether a directory exists. Just `md "directoryname"` and if the error message bothers you, `md "directoryname" 2>nul` where the `2>` redirects errormessages to *nowhere*

Comment: I tried this script http://pasteall.org/348649 but for some reason the folder is not created although the `CALL ECHO (%%folder%%^)` prints the correct new folder path, any thoughts?